# Fast Array Inserts with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

In Oracle OCI and OCCI there are API facilities to perform array inserts where you build up an array of values in the client and send this array along with a prepared statement to the server to insert thousands of entries into a table in a single shot resulting in huge performance improvements in some scenarios. Is there anything similar in PostgreSQL ?

I am using the stock PostgreSQL C API.

Some pseudo code to illustrate what i have in mind:

```
stmt = con->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ($1, $2, $3)");
pg_c_api_array arr(stmt);
for triplet(a, b, c) in mylongarray:
    pg_c_api_variant var = arr.add();
    var.bind(1, a);
    var.bind(2, b);
    var.bind(3, c);
stmt->bindarray(arr);
stmt->exec()
```

Comment: What language/PostgreSQL client API are you using?  This can make a difference as to what features can easily be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL has similar functionality - statement COPY and COPY API - it is very fast

[libpq documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-copy.html)

```
char *data = "10\t20\40\n20\t30\t40";

pres = PQexec(pconn, "COPY mytable FROM stdin");

/* can be call repeatedly */ 
copy_result = PQputCopyData(pconn, data, sizeof(data));
if (copy_result != 1)
{
        fprintf(stderr, "Copy to target table failed: %s\n",
                                        PQerrorMessage(pconn));
        EXIT;
}

if (PQputCopyEnd(pconn, NULL) == -1)
{
         fprintf(stderr, "Copy to target table failed: %s\n",
                                            PQerrorMessage(pconn));
                            EXIT;
}

pres = PQgetResult(pconn);
if (PQresultStatus(pres) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
{
       fprintf(stderr, "Copy to target table failed:%s\n",
                                            PQerrorMessage(pconn));
           EXIT;
}

PQclear(pres);
```

Comment: So is the data always rows of tab delimited values ? I take if one column is varchar then one must enclose in quotes or perhaps call PQ escape function ?

Comment: you can use any char like delimiter, tab is default delimiter - see COPY doc http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html

Answer (score 1):

As Pavel Stehule points out, there is the COPY command and, when using libpq in C, associated functions for transmitted the copy data.  I haven't used these.  I mostly program against PostgreSQL in Python, have have used similar functionality from psycopg2.  It's extremely simple:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(CONN_STR)
cursor = conn.cursor()
f = open('data.tsv')
cusor.copy_from(f, 'incoming')
f.close()
```

In fact I've often replaced `open` with a file-like wrapper object that performs some basic data cleaning first.  It's pretty seamless.

Comment: Its a pity that one needs to put the data into a file first. In my case i receive a coded file, decode values from the file and want to insert them directly from memory. Putting them back into a new (PostgreSQL copy coded) file seems unfortunate.

Comment: No, you can use COPY with stream or directly with data lines in string.

Comment: it doesn't have to be in a string.  One can pass binary data too: https://gist.github.com/ictlyh/12fe787ec265b33fd7e4b0bd08bc27cb

Answer (score 1):

I like this way of creating thousands of rows in a single command:

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (UNNEST($1), UNNEST($2), UNNEST($3));
```

Bind an array of the values of column 1 to `$1`, an array of the values of column 2 to `$2` etc.! Providing the values in columns may seem a bit strange at first when you are used to thinking in rows.

You need PostgreSQL >= 8.4 for `UNNEST` or your own function to convert arrays into sets.